# Why do my faces look as if normals are inconsistent when they are consistent?

Tags: modeling

In my viewport, some faces look like they are either disconnected from the rest of my mesh by means of duplicate vertices or edges, or they look like their normals are opposite to the rest of the mesh.

[image]

But the tools for fixing these problems fail to find such problems. According to these tools, there's no duplicates to merge, and the normals ARE consistent.

What other strange geometry problems could make my faces look inconsistent in my viewport?

Added a share of my file as requested:

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Visual problem with the normals is probably due to the length of the normals, so that they intersect with faces. Just decrease the size of the normals to get a better vision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your faces are shaded "smooth" and others "flat", select your mesh and hit either flat or smooth under the Tool-Menu -> Shading